# Três pontos no parâmetro de uma função em uma classe, pra que serve?

Tags: php

Estava inspecionando uma classe de um vendor do phpoffice chamada phpspreadsheet e encontrei a seguinte função no modulo Calculation.php... não é bem um problema, mas gostaria de entender o significado desta função, programo em php a 10 anos e nunca tinha visto 3 pontos dentro do parâmetro de uma função. Gostaria de saber o que isto significa, o que causa ou pra que serve! Segue a função

```
private static function mkMatrix(...$args)
{
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A partir da versão `5.6` foi implementado nos [argumentos da função](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php) as `...`, conhecido como *spread operator*. Isso quer dizer que a funcão/método receberá uma quantidade variável de argumentos e o tratará como um `array`.

Veja:

```
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

O retorno dessa função será

```
10
```

Você também pode utilizar para transformar um array/tranversable em uma lista:

```
function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

echo add(...[1, 2])."\n";

$a = [1, 2];
echo add(...$a);
```

@edit

Nas versões anteriores, até o `5.5`, ao passar uma quantidade variável de parâmetros em uma função, eles eram tratados utilizando as funções
[`func_num_args`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.func-num-args.php), [`func_get_arg`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.func-get-arg.php), [`func_get_args`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.func-get-args.php)

Fonte: [Argumentos de funções](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 0):

Desde [PHP 5.6](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) você também pode usar a `...$numbers` notação:

As [**funções variadicas**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) agora podem ser implementadas usando o `...` operador, em vez de confiar em func_get_args () .

```
function f($req, $opt = null, ...$params) {
    // $params is an array containing the remaining arguments.
    printf('$req: %d; $opt: %d; number of params: %d'."\n",
           $req, $opt, count($params));
}

f(1);
f(1, 2);
f(1, 2, 3);
f(1, 2, 3, 4);
f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

**O exemplo acima será exibido:**

```
$ req: 1; $ opt: 0; número de params: 0
$ req: 1; $ opt: 2; número de params: 0
$ req: 1; $ opt: 2; número de params: 1
$ req: 1; $ opt: 2; número de params: 2
$ req: 1; $ opt: 2; número de params: 3
```

fonte: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics