# Unificando valores de um array

Tags: php

Realizando uma consulta no banco de dados me retorna estes valores em um array denominado $arrayExcluir e necessito que estes value seja transferido para um array único (sem subdivisão) para que eu consiga usar para meus fins, este key deve ser com valor crescente (0,1,2..).

Como é exibido no navegador:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 48609
            [1] => 48613
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50847
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51709
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47686
        )
...
```

Em minhas pesquisas encontrei o array_column na documentação do php que só não funciona em meu código por pegar um "valor" de cada array, não pegando mais de um, gostaria que saber uma possível solução para meu problema.

Utilizando array_column prevê os seguintes campos:

> array_column(array, column_key, index_key)

É possível fazer isto va foreach ou apenas com array_column?

Utilizando este trecho de código:

```
array_column($arrayExcluir, 0));
```

ele me retorna apenas um value de cada, mas necessito de todos que estão em cada array..

Comment: já tentou usar array_merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
$res = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$arrayExcluir);
```

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

O que você possui é algo como:

```
$arrayExcluir = [[48609, 48613], [50847], [51709], [47686]];
```

Então basta utilizar a função `array_merge` para mesclar todos os *arrays* internos e, para tal, basta desconstruir o *array* original ao passá-lo por parâmetro:

```
$valores = array_merge(...$arrayExcluir);
```

Isso retornaria algo como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 48609
    [1] => 48613
    [2] => 50847
    [3] => 51709
    [4] => 47686
)
```

[Três pontos no parâmetro de uma função em uma classe, pra que serve?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273777/5878)